# Suspend trailing slash rule for sitemap file

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess rule that adds trailing slash if the request is without it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

I want to suspend the rule for the file sitemap.xml. That means I want to keep the adding slash rule for every request *but* sitemap.xml file.

Is it possible?

Comment: Good that you have shown your efforts and htaccess file in your question. For better understand of question could you please do add from which URL to which url(backend) you want to serve?

Comment: If the `sitemap.xml` is an existent file then your should not add a trailing slash  .(`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` ) already takes care of such files in your code.